# Tensorflow graph results appear random after restor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a model to predict the next word in a sequence. I saved the model using tf.train.Saver(). However, when I go to restore the model and supply it the same seed value, the output changes each time I run the testing. For example, if I supply it with the words "happy birthday to", it will predict "you", but then , if I run it 10 seconds later, it will predict "rhyno". I have a feeling that this might be due to me randomly initializing the internal layers to random normal weights, however, wouldn't restoring the model restore the values after training and not reinitialize the layers? My restore code is below:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
saved_model = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
    'C:/Users/me/my_model.meta')  # load graph from training
saved_model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
imported_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = imported_graph.get_operation_by_name("ph_x").outputs[0]
prediction = imported_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prediction:0')
run_input = seed_values
print(np.array2string(run_input, separator=" "))
for _ in range(production_size):
    run_input_oh = hlp.word_to_one_hot(run_input, hp_dict, 0)
    pred = hlp.one_hot_to_word(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: run_input_oh}), rev_dict)
    print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: run_input_oh}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You called default graph after restoring the saved weights. This will ignore restored weight.
Solution:
First call default graph, then restore the weights!

Try this!

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saved_model = tf.train.import_meta_graph(
            'C:/Users/me/my_model.meta')  # load graph from training
    imported_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    saved_model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    ...
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect this but the results are still random.

Comment: Try the session with a new graph instead of the default graph.
 new_graph = tf.Graph()
 with tf.Session(graph =new_graph) as sess:

Answer (score 0):

@midhun pk's answer is mistaken, calling `tf.get_default_graph()` does not modify the graph, and calling it before or after saved_model.restore makes no difference.

Your code seems fine (calling `import_meta_graph` adds the nodes of the saved graph to the current graph, and calling `restore` restores the states of the variables), and it's difficult to debug without more information about your model. (eg what are run_input, seed_values, etc?) Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

You should be able to verify if you variables are correctly restored by printing the value of the variable at save and restore time. Before saving, you can do `print(sess.run(variable))` (or use `tf.Print`). After restoring, you can check the weights of the restored variables as follows: Supposing your variable's name is "XX", do:

```
var_value = imported_graph.get_tensor_by_name("XX:0")
print(sess.run(var_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue, and it did not deal with the process of calling the saved weights.

When I first built the model for training, I created a dictionary from a text file by creating a set. In testing, I built the dictionary from the same text file, assuming that the order of elements would remain the same. Do not make this assumption. The order can change, hence the seemingly random results.